# A word problem about efficiency that is boggling me (Calculus)

Tags: calculus

[image]

I assigned this problem the other day to my class. It occurred to me that part b may not work, but I wanted to check. For part a, take the second derivative and set it equal to zero and solve.

$f'(x) = -3t^2 + 9t + 15$
$f''(x) = -6t + 9$

$-6t + 9 = 0 \Rightarrow t = \displaystyle\frac{3}{2}$ or 8:30am

For part b, consider the first derivative $-3t^2 + 9t + 15$. I tried computing the vertex but I got a negative number out of it. I also considered $Q'(5)$ but also got a negative.

It just occurred to me that maybe the word efficiently in this context is not a derivative. Maybe the problem merely asks to find the absolute minimum of this function. The answer in the back of the book is when $t = 5$ or noon.

Comment: Note that the vertex of the derivative is exactly the point where the second derivative is equal to zero (i.e., at $t=3/2$).

Answer (score 2):

The rate of production is, as you said, $-3t^2+9t+15$.  We want the minimum of this on the interval $[0,5]$, so need to check points where the derivative of it is zero, which is $t=\frac 32$ and the endpoints of the interval.  Checking the endpoints, the minimum is at $t=5$ when the rate of production is $-15$  You should call the lunch break at $11:11.556$ as the [production goes negative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3t%5E2%2B9t%2B15%3D0) about then.

Comment: When production goes negative, are the workers breaking the goods? How else can it be that $Q(5) < Q(4)$?

Comment: Under this model, yes, there are fewer goods at 12:00 than at 11:00. If I had a real factory, it would make me doubt the model.  As it is, I think the problem setter was more interested in a math problem than in making something realistic

Comment: The production going negative is what threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning "diminishing returns": If the worker is paid by hour the return to the employer per hour is
$$R(t):={Q(t)\over t}=-t^2+{9\over2} t+15\ .$$
As $R'(t)={9\over2}-2t$ the return per hour is increasing until $09\colon15$, and is diminishing from then on.